# Disable IPV4 on one interface using CMD

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, ipv4, network-interface

How can i make the same ad unchecking box IPV4 on internet connection properties, but using CMD, netsh, or sth. what i can put in .bat file?

Answer (score 1):

`netsh interface ipv4 uninstall`

This will require a reboot.

I believe this will disable system-wide, however.

Comment: yes, it will disable system-wide.
My goal is to have one NIC bridged for VirtualMachine, that i can easly switch on, and off IPV4, and one NIC always active with ipv4 on it.